# Switching to full site on code formatting error causes a 404 error

Tags: bug, error-message, bug-reporting-process

When answering a question and you get the error:

> Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:
>
> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

If you are on the mobile site when you got the above error and switch to full site while the error is being displayed you get Stack Overflow's 404 page error.

Is this error common? Are Stack Overflow developers aware of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mobile page doesn't do asynchronous validation; you get the error when you submit via /questions/ask/submit. This page only works when the question form is submitted along with the request (it's a POST request, not a GET request), and switching to/from mobile doesn't preserve that data - it just tries to redirect to the URL you were viewing.

You'll see the same error if, upon receiving a submission error, you simply reload the page (without re-submitting the data).

Efforts to make the normal /question/ask page responsive (== usable on mobile devices) are ongoing; once done, we should no longer need two separate ask pages, and everyone should get nice asynchronous errors.

[image: screenshot of responsive Gardening & Landscaping ask form]

Comment: Had me at `everyone should get nice asynchronous errors` :))